# how to transform string a array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This is a twitter, I need transform the string a an array, how to do make?, because I need to iterate through each element separately...

```
var twitter = 'RT Informacion sobre algo en comun @opmeitle #demodelor union J, http://bit.ly/a12, opmeitle@email.com';
```

I need something like that.

```
var result = ['RT, Informacion, sobre, algo, en, comun, @opmeitle, #demodelor, union, J, http://bit.ly/a12, opmeitle@email.com']

for ( i in result) { console.log(result[i]) } // output >> 
RT
Informacion
sobre
...
```

use, javascript or nodeJs

Comment: to transform the twitt into an array.

Comment: Do you want to split it into words?

Comment: something like this post! other example, > var string = "hi coldfusion stackoverflow"; i need var arrak = ["hi, coldfusion, stackoverflow"]

Comment: @opmeitle: Do you think `var arrak = ["hi, coldfusion, stackoverflow"]`is an array? It’s not. An array would be `var arrak = ["hi", "coldfusion", "stackoverflow"]`. What you wrote isn’t JavaScript.

Comment: you right , sorry! , no writer ' ' between eleem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me like you need something like this:

```
var string = "hi coldfusion stackoverflow";
var array = string.split(' ')
```

This code splits the string into an array through the argument passed into `.split` which in this case is a space, `" "`. When `.split` is executed, all the spaces (because we passed in a space) are removed and new elements(?) of an array are created in between the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

```
// This splits result into words -- /\s+/ is a regex
// that detects one or more whitespace characters
var twitt = 'foo bar baz quux';

var result = twitt.split(/\s+/);
// result is now ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'quux']

for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
    console.log(result[i]);
}
```

Avoid using `for in` loops to iterate over arrays.

Comment: this real problem!! var twitter = 'RT Informacion sobre algo en comun @opmeitle #demodelor union J, http://bit.ly/a12, opmeitle@email.com';